# AWS SendRawEmail operation: Illegal address error from multiple recipients

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an AWS Lambda that uses SES for sending emails.  This function works when I have only one recipient. But as soon as I add 2 or more recipients to the array, it fails with the following error.

I am in a Sandbox environment and saw that I had to verify the email domains that I am sending to. So that is no longer an issue.

```
"An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Illegal address"
```

My function is as follows below:

```
def send_email(sender, recipients, aws_region, subject,url):
    
    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=aws_region)
    
    BODY_TEXT = "Hi"
    BODY_HTML = """\
    <H1>Your Results have been process</h1>
    <br>
    {!s}
    </br>
    """.format(url)
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    msg['Subject'] = 'TOI Order Alert'
    
    # The character encoding for the email.
    CHARSET = "UTF-8"
    
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
    htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)
    
    
    # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msg_body.attach(textpart)
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)
   


    # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
    # parent container.
    msg.attach(msg_body)
    
    # Add the attachment to the parent container.
    # msg.attach(att)


    
    
    # Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations=[
                msg['To']
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            }
        )
        
    return("Email sent! Message ID:", response['MessageId'])
```

Here is the script of code the calls this function:

```
    # Send an email with the processed results

    sender = 'matt@test.awsapps.com'
    recipients = ['matt@gmail.com', 'talha@gmail.com']
    aws_region = os.environ["AWS_REGION"]
    subject='Testing Emails'
    URL = 'Google.com'
    
    
    
    response = mail.send_email(sender,recipients,aws_region,subject,url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing recipients as shown below worked for me. You can try the same in your code:

```
response = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=msg['From'],
            Destinations= recipients ,
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            }
        )
```